# Check column value in 2 different table with specific ID and return single value

Tags: php, mysql

**Tabel_1:**

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      fail
3      1002       test11     pass
4      1002       test12     pass
5      1002       test13     fail
```

**Tabel_2:**

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      pass
3      1001       test3      pass
4      1002       test11     pass
5      1002       test12     pass
6      1002       test13     fail
7      1002       test13     fail
```

I want to check passfail column in both table(Tabel_1 and Tabel_2) with specific test_id like 1001. if any of row has fail with specific id like 10001 then query will be returned only once fail or if any of row has no fail in column passfail then return value will be pass.

Comment: Can you also show us your expected output?

Comment: Result : fail  (Cos  id 2 of Tabel_1 has fail row for test_id 1001 . Thats why result will be fail.

Comment: has fail with specific id like 10001 - eh?

Comment: Tabel_1:

Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      Pass

Tabel_2:
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      pass
3      1001       test3      pass

Then result will be pass cos there was no fail in column passfail.

Comment: Do you want these results grouped by `testname`, or just by `test_id`?

Comment: Good grief. EDIT your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT test_id,min(passfail) as passfail FROM(
    SELECT * from table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table_2) as unioned
WHERE test_id = 1001
GROUP BY test_id
```

You don't need to join this tables and union all usually have better performance then a join. You can choose the min(passfail) for each one because fail is smaller, so if there is a fail value, it will be returned, and if not the pass will be returned

Comment: not to nitpick, as this answer is fine, but you need to alias your derived table to get this method to work.

Comment: @BuddyYaussy For that downvote?.. this answer works fine and have good performance.. Its not my fault that people downvoted your answer..

Comment: Looks like you got it, and no on the downvote, as I said, your union method works just fine...

Comment: This is the best answer. JOIN will not work if a test result appears in table 2, but not in table 1, as discovered by @shmosel